# php session: displaying a add or a remove button

Tags: php

I have had some help, and started a session, which saves a event ID (generated per page via wordpress) on click of a button.

It looks like this...

```
<form action="/addtobasket.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="101" />
<input type="submit" name="Add to Basket" />
</form>
```

and addtobasket.php is...

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['event_orders'][] = $_POST['event_id'];
?>
```

Now the issue(s) are that when I added

```
<?php
session_start();
foreach($_SESSION['event_orders'] AS $event_id){
echo 'Your ordered event ID is: ' .$event_id;
} ?>
```

In the header (just to test code was working) it can display multiple amounts of the same event ID depending if I clicked it more then once. I think a solution to stop this (as I only want user to be able to have 1 max of each event ID saved in a session) would be to display a remove button IF the person has the current event ID saved in their session, I kind of understand the logic, just not sure how to execute it, something to this effect...

(IF SESSION HAS CURRENT PAGE IF)
  show remove ID from session button (not sure how this looks)
(ELSE)
  show standard add ID button
(END)

Is this the correct logic? If so how do I execute this?

Much appreciated in advance for any help.

Comment: what is the meaning of the page ID? what is the event ID? is event id a product ID and you want to have each product only once in the cart?

Comment: Very sorry, I got mixed up, its not page id, its an Event ID (a plugin for wordpress) which is an unique number for each event page created, sorry I should have mentioned this.

Comment: And yes, exactly you should only be able to add a 'event' once i.e: cant add the same festival ticket twice)

Comment: Wait I will edit my question, its missing something

Answer (score 0):

If you store the event id in the key of the array, you can avoid double adding.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['event_orders'][ $_POST['event_id']] = true;
?>
```

Now the issue(s) are that when I added

```
<?php
session_start();
foreach($_SESSION['event_orders'] AS $event_id => $true){
echo 'Your ordered event ID is: ' .$event_id;
} ?>
```

Comment: If I use this code, it prints ID's in numerical order
ID:0 ID:1 ID:2 ID:3 ID:4 ID:5 (regardless if I clicked more then that)